# 16X2 lcd not working with pic16f887

Tags: microcontroller, lcd

i have been trying to interface a 16x2 lcd with pic16f887 microcontroller using mikro c. The code complies successfully but i am not getting the expected result when load on the microcontroller. The lcd only display black boxes on the first line but writes nothing. i have gone through my connections many times,also i have adjusted the contrast. i am using the lcd in 4-bit mode. the mikro c code is shown beolow.

```
// LCD module connections
sbit LCD_RS at RD0_bit;
sbit LCD_EN at RD1_bit;
sbit LCD_D4 at RD2_bit;
sbit LCD_D5 at RD3_bit;
sbit LCD_D6 at RD4_bit;
sbit LCD_D7 at RD5_bit;

sbit LCD_RS_Direction at TRISD0_bit;
sbit LCD_EN_Direction at TRISD1_bit;
sbit LCD_D4_Direction at TRISD2_bit;
sbit LCD_D5_Direction at TRISD3_bit;
sbit LCD_D6_Direction at TRISD4_bit;
sbit LCD_D7_Direction at TRISD5_bit;


// End LCD module connections

void main(){

  ANSEL  = 0;
  ANSELH = 0;
  C1ON_bit = 0;
  C2ON_bit = 0;


  Lcd_Init(); 
  Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);
  Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CURSOR_OFF);
  Lcd_Out(1,6,"seyi");
  }
```

Comment: A few things wrong here. Is this your entire code? If not, please paste your entire code. If it is, you're missing the configuration bit settings and whatever compiler-specific header file(s) for this MCU. Also, your code has no infinite loop. What do you think happens when it reaches that curly bracket on the last line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While wiring on hardware there are few thing to be noted like pin 3 should be properly connected with variable 10k resistor. If your programe is 110% ok but you have not connected pin 3 properly you will see nothing on LCD... There are some other problem too i suggest you to first simulate it on Proteus software then implement it on hardware. See this link describes how to interface lcd with pic using mikroC and common problem are disscussed with solution in details with pictures. It might help you

http://hassam794.weebly.com/interfacing-16x2-lcd-with-pic16f877a.html